# How can I load a ml file in toplevel of OCaml, just like `use mine.sml` in SML/NJ?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, sml

In `SML`'s `repl`, you can just type `use whatever.sml` and load all things inside that `.sml` into `repl`.

How can I do that in OCaml?

Comment: fml, why are there so many REPL questions? I want to load an .ml file from another in an actual program not the f'ing REPL lol. I don't understand why people even use a REPL...please educate me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have `#use` directive for that purpose:

> #use "file-name";;
>
> Read, compile and execute source phrases from the given file. This is textual inclusion: phrases are processed just as if they were typed on standard input. The reading of the file stops at the first error encountered.

For example (as per @gasche's suggestion):

```
# #use "whatever.ml";;
```

Here is a complete list of [OCaml directives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual023.html#toc91).

Comment: Note that the `#` of `#use` must really be typed by the user as an additional character, this is not a reference to the beginning prompt. The whole line will therefore look like `# #use "file.ml";;`. Users are frequently confused about this.

Comment: @gasche: Thanks, I added your example for clarification.

Comment: Link to ocaml directives is broken